# How do I turn off "shuffle" on my iPod Nano 7th Generation?

Tags: ipod-nano

I'd greatly appreciate help with learning how to shut off "shuffle" on my iPod Nano 7th Generation?

Answer (score 1):

Go into "settings", then "music" and change the shuffle setting from "on" to "off"

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: I have went to settings, then music, and change the shuffle setting from on to off but it still shuffles!!! Now what

Answer (score 0):

There is no turn off shuffle on iPod nano 7 gen